# Signal handling: how to parse code and status so WIFEXITED etc. can use them?

Tags: c, signals, children

sa_sigaction function takes argument siginfo_t which holds "si_code" and "si_status" depending on what changed child process'es state.
I'm using a library function that takes one integer being the status integer that you can pass to WIFEXITED, WIFTERMINATED, WIFSTOPPED etc. functions.

Is there a way to derive this integer from a siginfo_t struct?

Regards,
Danyel.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, meaning a child process has died. The signal handler can then use `waitpid()` to reap the exit status.

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
    /* use appropriate macros to check status */
}
```

If you are using `SA_SIGINFO`, then the second parameter to the `sa_sigaction` callback has the exit status:

```
if (info->si_code == CLD_EXITED) {
    /* info->si_status is the exit status */
}
```

However, you still need to wait on the child process explicitly to reap the process from the process table.

Comment: how did i overlook this simple way... a simple `waitpid(info->si_pid, &status, WNOHANG)` was all I needed. Why thank you, jxh. :)

Comment: Can you explain more about how you obtained `info`? Was it from a call to `waitid()`?

Comment: `struct sigaction action;
action.sa_sigaction = myHandler;
action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &action, 0)`
The myHandler function has three parameters, the second of which is siginfo_t. That one holds the si_pid, si_code and si_status members. See sigaction(2) for more information.